# How to check if a location is inside a circle on a map

Tags: matlab, dictionary, geometry

I'm trying to check if a location lat/long is inside a circle on a map using Matlab. I used this formula :

```
d=R*acos(sin(S_lat(t)*d2r)*sin(N_lat*d2r)+cos(S_lat(t)*d2r)*cos(N_lat*d2r)*cos((S_long(t)-N_long)*d2r))
```

and the following formula:

```
a = sin((S_lat(t)-N_lat)*d2r / 2)^2 + cos(N_lat*d2r) * cos(S_lat(t)*d2r) * sin((S_long(t)-N_long)*d2r / 2)^2;
c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a));
d = R * c;
```

But it didn't give me the right answers.

Comment: This is simply checking that the distance is within certain KM / Miles to the center point of the circle right? There are implementations of this. If this is not a programming exercise I would go for that approach.

Comment: I want to compare the distance between the center of my circle and the location to the radius of the circle!

Answer (score 0):

Your second formula for distance looks almost right comparing with [this page](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
d = R ⋅ c
```

As far as I see, `asin` should give the same result as `atan2` formula in the second line for positive arguments in range 0..1.
If value of `a` may lie slightly outside this interval, arcsine will give erroneous result, so

> If atan2 is not available, c could be calculated from 2 ⋅ asin( min(1,
> √a) ) (including protec­tion against rounding errors).

Could you show an example of data points with mistakes?

Python code ([ideone to play with)](https://ideone.com/oXQnSF)

```
import math
def eadist(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    print(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
    d2r = math.pi / 180
    R = 6378
    dlat = (lat2 -lat1) * d2r
    dlon = (lon2 -lon1) * d2r
    a = (math.sin(dlat/2))**2 + math.cos(lat1*d2r)*math.cos(lat2*d2r) * (math.sin(dlon/2))**2
    print("a=",a)
    c = 2*math.asin(math.sqrt(a))
    print("c=",c)
    dist = c * R
    return dist

print(eadist(45, 90, 45, 91))
print(eadist(45, 90, 46, 90))
print(eadist(45, 90, 46, 91))
print(eadist(45, 90, -45, -90))
```

gives correct results

```
45 90 45 91
a= 3.8076210902190215e-05
c= 0.012341263173265506
78.71257651908739  //1 degree by parallel

45 90 46 90
a= 7.615242180438042e-05
c= 0.017453292519943295
111.31709969219834   //1 degree by meridian

45 90 46 91
a= 0.0001135583120069672
c= 0.021313151879913415
135.93528269008777   //diagonal step

45 90 -45 -90
a= 1.0
c= 3.141592653589793
20037.0779445957   //antipodal point, a half of meridian length
```

Comment: THank you for your answer. Here is the code i used to just check if any of this formulas give me the right answer by ploting a circle and then recalculate its radius but unfortunately they don't give me the right value.

Comment: Can you see please check my code that i posted as an answer.. and thank you again!

Comment: Check intermediate results and compare with Python ones

Comment: Thank you for you response, but it doesn't give me the right values. I think that this formula computes  the arclength but what i want is to compute the shortest distance between two points on a map.

Comment: You can see that function gives **correct distance** in kilometers between two points

Answer (score 0):

R=6378;        %Earth raius
d2r = pi/180;  %degrees to radians

N_lat=45;
N_long=90;

rov=70;

[latc,longc] = scircle1(N_lat,N_long,rov);%copute a circle with (N_lat,N_long)as a center and rov its radius

D=zeros(1,length(latc));
%Check if the distance from the center of the circle to any point of its
%perimeter is equal to rov using this formulas

for i =1:length(latc)

```
% Formula1
%D(i)=acos(sin(latc(i)*d2r)*sin(N_lat*d2r)+cos(latc(i)*d2r)*cos(N_lat*d2r)*cos((longc(i)-N_long)*d2r));
```

%  Formula2
%  D(i)=R*sqrt((latc(i)-N_lat)^2+(longc(i)-N_long)^2);

%Formula3
% a = sin((latc(i)-N_lat)*d2r / 2)^2 + cos(N_lat*d2r) * cos(latc(i)*d2r) * sin((longc(i)-N_long)*d2r / 2)^2;
% c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a));
% D(i) = R * c;
%Formula4
% D(i)=R*distance(latc(i),longc(i),N_lat,N_long);

end

Answer (score 0):

**By vector geometry and spherical coordinates:**

You can turn the longitude/latitude angles to Cartesian coordinates on the unit sphere by

```
X = cos(Θ) sin(φ), Y = sin(Θ) sin(φ), Z = cos(φ)
```

You can compute these for the test point and the center of the circle. Then the arc cosine of the dot product gives you the central angle, which you can compare to the radius of the circle* over the radius of the Earth.

---

*Arc length, not radius in the circle plane.

Comment: it doen't really work. I tried (distance('gc', latc(i),longc(i),N_lat,N_long)). It's a function given by matlab but it gives me the right answer just for small radius.

Comment: @Naj: what doesn't work ? What I show is bulletproof, did you even try it ?

Comment: Yes i just tried it! Indeed, to clear up the task i'm working on,  i plotted a moving circle on a map and i want to check where a certain location is inside the circle while it is moving, this is why i have to compare the distance between the center of my circle and this location to the radius.

Comment: Can I see your code ? There is no reason it does not work.

Comment: x=cos(latc*d2r)*cos(longc*d2r)-cos(N_lat*d2r)*cos(N_long*d2r);
y=cos(latc*d2r)*sin(longc*d2r)-cos(N_lat*d2r)*sin(N_long*d2r);
z=sin(latc*d2r)-sin(N_lat*d2r);

c=sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2);
angle=asin(c/2);
D=R*angle;
Where (N_lat, N_long) is my location and (latc, longc) is the center of the circle.

Comment: @Naj: This has nothing to do with my answer.

Comment: That's what you were meaning maybe ?x=cos(latc*d2r)*cos(longc*d2r)*cos(N_lat*d2r)*cos(N_long*d2r);
y=sin(latc*d2r)*sin(longc*d2r)*sin(N_lat*d2r)*sin(N_long*d2r);
z=cos(latc*d2r)*cos(N_lat*d2r);

angle=acos(x+y+z);
D=R*angle;

Comment: @Naj: there are mistakes.

Comment: Can you please tell me more about it!

Comment: I can't really see, i just calculate the dot product directly and then i multiply the angle by the Earth radius to compare it to my radius.

Comment: @Naj: double check the cosines and sines. Your code is not so readable, which can be a cause of failure.

Answer (score 0):

```
 R=6378;        %Earth raius
 d2r = pi/180;  %degrees to radians  

N_lat=45;
N_long=45;
rov=50;

%World map
        worldmap world
        load coastlines
        [latcells, loncells] = polysplit(coastlat, coastlon);
        plotm(coastlat, coastlon, 'green')
   
hold on;
plotm(N_lat,N_long,'b*');
hold on;
[latc,longc] = scircle1(N_lat,N_long,rov);%compute a circle with (N_lat,N_long)as a center and rov its radius
plotm(latc,longc,'r-');

D=zeros(1,length(latc));
%Check if the distance from the center of the circle to any point of its
%perimeter is equal to rov using this formulas

for i =1:length(latc)
%     
%     % Formula1
%     %D(i)=acos(sin(latc(i)*d2r)*sin(N_lat*d2r)+cos(latc(i)*d2r)*cos(N_lat*d2r)*cos((longc(i)-N_long)*d2r));
%     
% %  Formula2        
% %  D(i)=R*sqrt((latc(i)-N_lat)^2+(longc(i)-N_long)^2);
% 
% %Formula3
% % a = sin((latc(i)-N_lat)*d2r / 2)^2 + cos(N_lat*d2r) * cos(latc(i)*d2r) * sin((longc(i)-N_long)*d2r / 2)^2;
% % c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a));
% % D(i) = R * c;
% 
% %Formula4
% 
% D(i)=distance('gc', latc(i),longc(i),N_lat,N_long);

% %Formula5
% x = (longc(i)-N_long)*d2r*cos((latc(i)+N_lat)*d2r/2);
% y = (latc(i)-N_lat)*d2r; 
% D(i)=R*sqrt(x^2+y^2);

%Formula6
 
x=cos(latc(i)*d2r)*cos(longc(i)*d2r)-cos(N_lat*d2r)*cos(N_long*d2r);
y=cos(latc(i)*d2r)*sin(longc(i)*d2r)-cos(N_lat*d2r)*sin(N_long*d2r);
z=sin(latc(i)*d2r)-sin(N_lat*d2r);

c=sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2);
angle=asin(c/2);
D(i)=R*angle;

end

    enter code here
```

Comment: That 's the code I used. I tried to make sure that this formula will really work, so i calculate the distance between the center of my circle and the locations generated by scircle1 , so logically i have to get the value of the radius that i used to plot my circle but that'not what my code gives. @Yves Daoust